# If the 12% of a required number is $\sqrt{22+8\sqrt{16}} - \sqrt{22-8\sqrt{16}}$, what is the required number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

So $12$% of the required number is $\sqrt{22+8\sqrt{16}} - \sqrt{22-8\sqrt{16}}$. I was initially defining the first part of the term as $x$ and the second as $y$ and then raising both to the power of $2$. But that does not seem to do anything. So I just applied a brute force approach:

$\sqrt{22+8\sqrt{16}} = \sqrt{22+32}=\sqrt{54}$ and the other one is $i\sqrt{10}$. Therefore the solution is $25(\sqrt{6}-i\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{10})$. It looks a bit ugly and I am pretty sure there is a neater way to solve this.

Comment: Seems to be a direct way to solve this problem. You can also try the adjacent trick $\sqrt x - \sqrt y = \frac{x - y}{\sqrt x + \sqrt y}$, but I don't see any upside of using it here.

Comment: Anyway $\sqrt{-10}$ could also be $-i\sqrt{10}$ as well.

Comment: I assume $(22+8*16^{1/3})^{1/3}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote with $x$ the required number. Then you know that $$\frac{12}{100}x=\sqrt{22+8\sqrt{16}} - \sqrt{22-8\sqrt{16}}$$ which implies that $$x=\frac{100}{12}\left(\sqrt{22+8\sqrt{16}} - \sqrt{22-8\sqrt{16}}\right)$$

Comment: Hmm... This is a mathematics olympiad question I was thinking that the answer you provided cannot be the one they are looking for. Very strange question.

Comment: Yes, it is too simple for a mathematics olympiad

Comment: Related to the fact that if 12.0% of a required number is $A$, then the required number is $\frac{A}{0.120}$.